# Sony SmartWatch - what is the host application (AHA)

Tags: android, sony, accessory, sony-smartwatch

I want to extend an application to communicate with the sony smartwatch under usage of the control API. I am new at developing extensions for the sony smartwatch and I did not understand what the AHA is and where it is located??? What do I have to implement on my own? Do I need to implement AEA and AHA?

In my opinion the AHA is the application that should be extended to communicated/work with the smartwatch (if it is available).

What do I need to get my application working with the sony smartwatch (SDK and LiveWareManager already running)???

EDIT:
What do I have to modify/add on my plain old android application in order to work with an extension or get an extension started??? I already installed one of the samples from the sdk on my android phone and now want to talk to it?!? ;-)

Thanks in advance for your help!!! ;-)

Comment: I realized it with a simple broadcast receiver ... the main application sends itents to the AEA which is responsible for the smartwatch!

Answer (score 2):

The AHA is specific to a particular Smart accessory model and should be supplied by the accessory maker (Sony). You as a 3rd party developer can use the SmartExtensions API (which communicated with the AHA) and the Android APIs to create AEAs.

You can find some samples and a short tutorial in the Code_examples folder in the SmartExtensions SDK.